# Check if elasticsearch query results are coming from cache or not?

Tags: elasticsearch, caching

I need to compare the 2 different indices(same data with different no of shards) for an elastic-search index, for which I am using some of my slow search queries and hitting on these indices but I am suspecting as one indices is getting the live traffic, hence its possible for my queries results are coming from cache.

**Is there is any way to figure out, results are coming from cache or any param which we can specify to not bring results from cache ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default, the requests cache will only cache the results of search
>   requests where  **size=0**, so it will not cache `hits`, but it will
>   cache `hits.total`, `aggregations`, and `suggestions`.

The `request_cache` query-string parameter can be used to **enable or disable** caching on a per-request basis. If set, it overrides the index-level setting:

```
GET /my_index/_search?request_cache=true
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "popular_colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "colors"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**SEE MORE:** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html#_enabling_and_disabling_caching_per_request

Comment: But this will only disable the shard level request cache and not the node level query cache